# Parse a string of 0 and 1 into a BitArray

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

Is it possible to parse a string of 0 and 1 into a BitArray or Byte or any other bit oriented object? What bit oriented object or library should I use to help me to manipulate bits?

Comment: you can use `BitArray` collection

Comment: sorry, for asking but did you try to research before posting? As to the second question: [try the BitArray](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.bitarray?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Do you mean parsing a string with binary number to get decimal number?

Comment: Of course I did a search but I never found any answer of this. Strange...